# how to log work for a given issue using jira soap?

Tags: ruby, soap, jira

I'm working on a ruby on rails app which connects to Jira through jira soap.  I browsed through the Jira SOAP API documentation but could not figure out a way to log time for an issue.  What method(s) do I've to use to allow users to log time for some issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addWorklogAndAutoAdjustRemainingEstimate is the one I'm using in my scripts

This is a snippet of python code that might be useful to you:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = "%s-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:00+01:00"%(d.year,d.month,d.day,d.hour,d.minute);

log = self.client.factory.create("ns0:RemoteWorklog")
log.comment = comment # a string
log.timeSpent = time # in the usual format (2h30m )
log.startDate = timestamp

# task is the name of the tast (a string)
self.client.service.addWorklogAndAutoAdjustRemainingEstimate(self.auth,task,log)
```

Answer (score 1):

Via the [addWorkLogXxx](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#addWorklogAndAutoAdjustRemainingEstimate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteWorklog%29) methods, where `Xxx` is what to do with the estimate.

Answer (score 0):

for ruby developers, 
worklog class from jira4r gem can be accessed via : `Jira4R::V2::RemoteWorklog`